# How do I change the taglines next to the featured image on my posts?

Tags: blog

I don't mean how do I change the tagline of the website, I mean when I am posting blog posts which will appear on my website, how can I edit that?

Comment: You'll need to be more clear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to change the excerpts for your posts?